# Python: how to add function to a class

Tags: python, class, object

Let me say that I am pretty new in working with Object Oriented programming in Python, so let me explain the problem. I defined this class

```
class Driver(object):
        def __init__(self, name, raw_value, Ind1, Ind2, Ind3, Ind4, Ind5):
            self.name = name
            self.raw = raw_value
            self.Indicator1 = Ind1  
            self.Indicator2 = Ind2 
            self.Indicator3 = Ind3  
            self.Indicator4 = Ind4 
            self.Indicator5 = Ind5
```

Then for each indicator I have to do this operation where `A` is a list containing the values I need and `A[i].Indicator1` contains the values of the `Indicator1` for the driver`i`, `A[i].Indicator2` the `Indicator2`, and so on.

```
indicator1 = {}
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    if not A[i].name in indicator1:
        indicator1[A[i].name] = [A[i].Indicator1]
    else:
        indicator1[A[i].name] += [A[i].Indicator1]

    for i in range(0,len(drivers)):
        tmp = []
        if len(indicator1[drivers[i]]) < 10: continue
        tmp = pd.concat(indicator1[drivers[i]]).values
```

similarly for the `Indicator2`

```
indicator2 = {}
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    if not A[i].name in indicator2:
        indicator2[A[i].name] = [A[i].Indicator2]
    else:
        indicator2[A[i].name] += [A[i].Indicator2]

    for i in range(0,len(drivers)):
        tmp = []
        if len(indicator2[drivers[i]]) < 10: continue
        tmp = pd.concat(indicator2[drivers[i]]).values
```

and so on for the other indicators.

I am wondering how to that using a special `class` function.

Comment: class *method* is the right wording

Comment: thanks, instead of `function`?

Comment: Yes. Functions are *first class* objects in python. Classes have methods

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relationship between your lowercase `indicatorX` dictionaries, the `drivers` sequence and instances of the `Driver` class, but I will give a general suggestion: Variable or attribute names with numbers tacked on the end usually should be lists or tuples (or rarely, dictionaries) instead. That way you can handle them in a loop, rather than repeating yourself a bunch of times with almost-identical code.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye thanks.